# How to create a linear regression line with .nc files over 30 year periods

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, netcdf, python-xarray

I am currently lost on how to go about creating a linear regression line with my 30-yr precipitation data. The file is too large to turn into a csv and was wondering if there is a method I should use to plot precipitation over time, specifically seasons of 30 years.

```
import netCDF4
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

nc = xr.open_dataset('/Users/name/Desktop/my_project_DO_NOT_ERASE/precip/cru_ts4.06.1901.2021.pre.dat.nc')


nc.variables.keys()

lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
time_var = nc.variables['time'][:]
precip = nc.variables['pre'][:]




<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lon: 720, lat: 360, time: 1452)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 -179.8 -179.2 -178.8 -178.2 ... 178.8 179.2 179.8
  * lat      (lat) float32 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 -88.25 ... 88.75 89.25 89.75
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1901-01-16 1901-02-15 ... 2021-12-16
Data variables:
    pre      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    stn      (time, lat, lon) float64 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.4
    title:        CRU TS4.06 Precipitation
    institution:  Data held at British Atmospheric Data Centre, RAL, UK.
    source:       Run ID = 2204291347. Data generated from:pre.2204291209.dtb
    history:      Fri 29 Apr 16:08:23 BST 2022 : User f098 : Program makegrid...
    references:   Information on the data is available at http://badc.nerc.ac...
    comment:      Access to these data is available to any registered CEDA user.
    contact:      support@ceda.ac.uk
```

I have tried converting to csv, but it will not work and shuts down the kernel in both jupyter notebook and spyder. I would like to try seaborn that only takes dataframes.

Comment: Is the data too large to hold in memory? It would help if you showed us more about your data - pasting the result of `print(ds)` as a code block into your question would be a good start. And can you show us the code you tried, along with any error messages?

Comment: See [ask]. It's unclear and unspecific. Why are you trying to convert to a csv file? You mean you can't use ```xarray.Variable``` directly?

Comment: I am trying to plot the precipitation on the y -axis and the time over 30 years on the x-axis. I preferably do not want to convert to csv, I would like to either use numpy or xarray to do this.

Comment: When you’re saying csv do you mean pandas.DataFrame? Those are very different things. Also, please clarify if your goal is the linear regression or the plot? I would take very different approaches to these. And do you really want to put all locations and time steps on the same plot? The plot will be very noisy I expect. Or do you want to eg average spatially or select points first?